# How to quickly change both opening and closing parentheses to a different type?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webstorm

Is there a way to quickly change both opening and closing parentheses to a different type?

For example: `(...some code...)` to `{...some code...}`

I know that <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> jumps between matching braces, so you could select the block, surround it with new bracket type, then jump around to remove the old set of braces but was wondering if there is a better way.

**Update**

While making a screen recording of it "not working", I saw for the first time this feature in action. However, it only seems to work from `()` to `{}`. As the capture shows, it doesn't work the other way. I guess that is why I couldn't get it to work before.

Sorry the GIF is a slowed down version of the original video.

I wonder why it only works one way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the opening `(`, type a `{` and IntelliJ changes the closing part accordingly. This apparently does not work when editing the closing part.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. If I keep my cursor just before the bracket, and add a new one, there is no closing bracket appearing. If I select the opening bracket, the closing bracket gets added at the end of the selection.

Comment: @VladL Is it possible to provide short screencast demonstrating the issue? It seems to work fine on my side.

Comment: @y.bedrov I made a recording and added an "update" section to my answer. For me it only seems to work going from () to {}. I must've tried the other way round before, and it didn't work. Weird that it only works one way?